# Not downloading a file correctly

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm using the following line to download a file, and when I do that, it's not downloading the most recent file.

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("http://example.com/users.txt"), _T("users.txt"), 0, NULL);
```

On the first run, users.txt has 3 names in it, if you were to remove a name, and run it again it still downloads with 3 names.

I'm using `remove("users.txt);` to remove the file prior to download.

Comment: What does "users.txt has 3 names in it" means to you?

Comment: Say it has 3 entries, "Bob", "Joe", and "Frank" on three separate lines.

Comment: Did you try disabling caching?

Comment: Disabling the cache with `DeleteUrlCacheEntry(url);` worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, or at least you need a library for [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client side.

<sup>You need to read a lot more about the HTTP protocol. The formulation of your question makes me believe you don't understand much about it.</sup>

On some OSes (notably Linux and POSIX compliant ones), you can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (which is a good HTTP client free software library)

[URLDownloadToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be a Windows specific thing. Did you carefully read its documentation? It is returning some error code. Do you handle `hr` correctly?

You can probably only get what the HTTP protocol (response from web server, for a `GET` HTTP request) gives you. Mostly, the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of the content of the URL, the content size, and the content bytes (etc... including content encoding etc...). The fact that the content has 3 names is your understanding of it.

Try to read more about the HTTP protocol, and understand what is really going on. Are any cookies or sessions involved? Did you try to use something like [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) to manually make the HTTP exchange? Are you able to show it and understand it? What it the HTTP response code ?

If you  have access to the server (e.g. using `ssh`) and are able to look into the log files, try to understand what exchanges happened and what HTTP status -i.e. error code- was sent back. Perhaps set up some Linux box locally for initial tests. Or setup some HTTP server locally and use `http://localhost/` etc...